# Javascript Else statement copies status element instead of replacing

Tags: javascript

I am working on a piece of code but got a slight issue with it. What I got is an error message that is combined with a error code.

The message can be altered by a backend user.
The code is generated by Google.

## The error message:

As said above the error message can be altered by the user in the backend of the Joomla CMS System. This is then saved and retrieved as a PHP variable. This variable is then inputted into the div with ID "gmd-alert".

I use innerHTML to retrieve that text. Since I can't use the php variable into js.

## The error code:

This code is generated by Google and usually gives something like `NOT_FOUND`

## Why combining?

1. The end product should be usuable on different languages and the user should be therefore able to modify the error message.
2. When relying only on the error code (status) it is not clear for the visitor of the website what now the error is.

## Partial code

The code in question is below:

```
if (status === 'OK') {
  var d = document.getElementById("gmd-alert");
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
} else {
  //window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  var d = document.getElementById("gmd-alert");
  d.className -= " gmd-hidden";
  d.className += " gmd-visible";
  d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + status;
  setTimeout(function(){
    d.className -= " gmd-visible";
    d.className += " gmd-hidden";
  }, 2000);
}
```

The problem is when the else statement is run multiple times it then displays something like this: `errormessage errorcode errorcode errorcode`

How can I make it run like this: `errormessage errorcode` even if it is fired 20x times.

---

In other words when firing the else function 3 times it gives:
`innerHTML status status status` but I want `innerHTML status`

---

The innerHTML is a userdefined text that is inserted via PHP.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Here is your problem: d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + status; should be d.innerHTML = status

Comment: What do you think `d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + status;` does?

Comment: @Eric I understand where you are coming from but the innerHTML part contains a piece of text that is inserted by PHP. If I do what you suggest I will be losing that piece of text.

Comment: @PM77-1 Add the moment innerHTML shows the following: `Directions request failed due to` and the error code shows `NOT_FOUND`

Comment: Maybe check the value of d.className and only if it has gmd-hidden go ahead and do the appending, else return

Comment: @SandeepRajoria That is indeed a good idea.

Comment: @purple11111 I think it shud work... happy to help!!

Comment: `d.className -= " gmd-hidden";` You can not subtract strings! That is NOT how you remove a class from the list of classes.

Comment: @epascarello why does it work then? Because it works I left it in. Feel free to share how to do it then?

Comment: It is not working.... The bug somehow makes it work.... [MDN classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) A simple test would show you that the result would be NaN since you can not subtract strings.

Comment: @epascarello So instead of supplying a solution you rather be a computer cowboy downvote everything and think you are a god or something. I tried the code without the minus and the result is that the class is not removed. So I put the minus back and then the class is removed. And yes you are correct it is adding NaN but it is also removing the code. So come with a solution instead of just criticizing. You are not even answering the question. So what are you actually doing just down voting for fun?

Comment: @purple11111 It removes it because of a bug... It will also remove any other class you have set previously. If you follow the link for classList I provided you can call the add and remove methods and magically it will be correct.

Comment: @epascarello I just read your link and I will be honest I did not saw it at first. But after reading it I have no idea how to implement it with the code above. Would you be so kind to do it? UPDATE: Nevermind modified my answer with the corrected code. The bug is now fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While all the other answers and comments on this page are correct I needed in this instance another solution. Luckily one of the comments brought me on the next idea. Basically I get the PHP variable and insert that into the innerHTML. Now it does what I want.

```
        if (status === 'OK') {
          var d = document.getElementById("gmd-alert");
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          //window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          var alerttext_var = "<?php echo $alerttext; ?>";
          var d = document.getElementById("gmd-alert");
          d.className = "gmd-visible";
          d.innerHTML = alerttext_var + status;
          setTimeout(function(){
            d.className = "gmd-hidden";
            d.innerHTML = alerttext_var;
          }, 2000);
        }
```

Thanks to everyone for helping. Even when I did not use your solution I really appreciate your input!

Comment: Well there is a bug in the code. Fix the bug, and the downvote will be removed.

Comment: @epascarello Bug is fixed but not on the way you suggested. Or you did suggest it like this and I just did not understood it like that. Anyway it is fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @epascarello What I still don't understand is why can we + it but don't - it. It seems logic? Is it possible to explain this to me like I am a 3 year old? PS: Thanks for removing the downvote.

Comment: Because strings have concatenation. Strings do not have subtraction, multiplication, or division. When you try to do any of those operations it tries to change the strings into a number and do the operation. So basically it is `var className = parseFloat("a string") - parseFloat("another");`

Comment: Ah now I see. I was thinking it would do a sort of find and replace. Now I understand where you are coming from. Thanks for explaining it to me!

Answer (score -1):

Add a flag that's initially set to false, to keep track of whether or not you've updated the status. In the example below we use a variable called statusUpdated.

```
var statusUpdated = false;
if (status === 'OK') {
  var d = document.getElementById("gmd-alert");
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
} else if(statusUpdated === false) {
  statusUpdated = true;
  //window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  var d = document.getElementById("gmd-alert");
  d.className -= " gmd-hidden";
  d.className += " gmd-visible";
  d.innerHTML += status;
  setTimeout(function(){
    d.className -= " gmd-visible";
    d.className += " gmd-hidden";
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code and sadly it is having the same behaviour. PS: I did not do the downvote. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I'm confused. My solution should absolutely work. So there's an important piece of information we're missing. (I think :-/)

Comment: Let me try to modify the question so it is more clear. Writing a clear question is sometimes rather difficult :-)

Comment: @purple11111 Make sure the first line of my example (var statusUpdated = false) is only ever run once. In other words, move that line outside of the block that the code above resides in. I assume that the above function is in a callback of some kind. Move that first lien outside of that callback.

Comment: Hey @Tyler Biscoe I modified the question with more info and added the code that I have from you. Did I place it in the correct position? Sadly it is still giving the same result.

Comment: I think you just have to take my concept and run with it. Keep track of whether or not that status has been updated, and only do it if it hasn't yet. Alternatively, you may add a span element inside of the gmd-alert element, and update its innerHTML. That way you can update it over, and over again without impacting the rest of the contents.

Comment: @purple11111 Here's an example of what I mean about the alternative solution: http://codepen.io/biscoe916/pen/GrvaYL

Comment: I solved it on a different way but your way looks more interesting. Thanks so much for your continues help! I love it.

Comment: Happy to help. Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score -1):

Simply save the content of d.innerHTML **BEFORE** adding msg to it (on page load since the text will be added by PHP from what I understand).

```
var text = '<?php echo $your_text; ?>';
```

then you can do

```
d.innerHTML = text + status;
```

Comment: That's doing in two lines what he's already doing in one. Also, innerHTML isn't a function.

Comment: No. Read again. OP says he wishes to keep some text added by PHP THEN do it's else case

Comment: How is this: `d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + status;`, different than what you're doing in this answer.

Comment: Read again. text is the text on load added by PHP. text never changes after onload.

Comment: I read your answer before I downvoted it. I maintain that it's incorrect. Also, innerHTML is NOT a function. So there is an obvious syntax error as well. innerHTML(), should be innerHTML;

Comment: Did you really update your answer to fix the problem I pointed out, then pretend it was like that all along while accusing me of being illiterate? For future readers: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41860449/revisions (lol)

Comment: No, OP stated in his comments that the initial value is set from PHP. Hence me telling op to first catch the content, hence me telling you to read before downvoting my friend. See his 3rd comment THANK YOU BASED BLIND DOWNVOTER